# Querying GraphQL to lookup an object based on id OR name

Tags: node.js, graphql

I have defined in my types the following query. I set up a nodejs and expressGraphQL server.

```
type Query {
  product(_id: ID!): Product!
  products: [Product!]!
}
```

However, in my front end I also want to request a specific Product based on a Title (or unique string, derived from the url). How can I change the query for product so it accepts either an ID or a String of Title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a `InputType` with both `ID` and `String` as optional but require the `InputType`, then handle both cases in the resolver.

Something like:

```
input ProductSearch {
    id: ID
    title: String
}

type Product {
    id: ID!
    title: String
}

type Query {
  product(search: ProductSearch!): Product!
  products: [Product!]!
}
```

And in your resolver you can handle the cases like:

```
Query: {
    product: (source, args) => {
        if (args.search.id) {
            // here you have id
            console.log(args.search.id)
        }
        if (args.search.title) {
            // here you have title
            console.log(args.search.title)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes `input`, that is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!